# Environment font size is too small

Tags: fonts, kubuntu

So I've chosen a font by

System Settings -> Application Appearance -> Fonts

And there I've adjusted all fonts to be of 14th size. And also checked "Use my KDE fonts..." in Gtk+ appearance. I've also did the same using

```
kdesudo systemsettings
```

But still some fonts are tiny! It's not the 14th size!

[image]

**Edit 2**:

I thought it might be one of Gnome font settings. So I've increased all fonts in

```
gnome-tweak-tool
sudo gnome-tweak-tool
gconf-editor
sudo gconf-editor
```

No help!

**Edit**:

Ubuntu tweak also gives no help (note the tiny fonts!):

[image]

**Edit**:

It looks like the problem is with gtk3: when I compile emacs 24.0.92 with gtk3 - i get small menu fonts. When I do the same with a default gtk2 - everything is all right.

Comment: Is your screen's DPI correct? I found that when X assumed a 96 DPI on a screen that's 1366x768 and 11" (so, really 135 DPI!) fonts were far too small. If `xrandr` shows it's incorrectly detecting display size, you can forcibly change it to the correct size https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Setting_xrandr_commands_in_kdm.2BAC8-gdm_startup_scripts

Comment: It seems to be correct: `1600x900       59.9*+`. The problem is still around.

Comment: @fossfreedom: Following Your advice I tried that - and have found that `ubuntu-tweak` doesn't change a signle font for me - nor does `sudo ubuntu-tweak`.

Comment: Please add to your question what version of Kubuntu you are using, how you installed it and if this is an upgrade.  Please describe if you have installed any other desktop environments such as Unity, gnome-shell etc.

Comment: Deleted, sorry that Ubuntu Tweak didn't do the trick!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some gnome lib is missing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71433/some-gnome-lib-is-missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved by installing

```
gtk3-engines-oxygen-git
gtk2-engines-oxygen-git
```

from [here](https://launchpad.net/~hrvojes/+archive/kde-goodies).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a known bug in KDE, where the font size of the shutdown dialogue is not affected by system settings. Please vote for the bug on the bug tracker if you would like it fixed.

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211501

Comment: I have small font here-and-there - not only at the shutdown dialog. I do believe it is because KDE can't link some Gnome config in the right way.

Comment: No, that is not correct. The reason for the small font in the shutdown dialog is because the size is hard-coded. grep for 'setPixelSize' in [the code](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kde-workspace/repository/revisions/master/entry/ksmserver/shutdowndlg.cpp). Where else do you see incorrect fonts?

Comment: Well - for example in the second screenshot in the question - the fonts are tiny. Where else? If I compile emacs with gtk3 - the menu fonts are tiny, in any dialog regarding root - despite I've configured all root settings to the 14th size of DejaVu Mono.

Comment: @Adobe this bug has now been fixed https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216853