# Some gnome lib is missing

Tags: gnome, kde, shutter

I've just installed Kubuntu 11.10 - and it looks like some gnome lib is missing - selectors like that:

[image]

doesn't work: I can not choose with a mouse tabs on the left. I've installed gnome-common but it gave no help.

[image: Another example: AutoKey with gtk]

Comment: What broken menu are you talking about?

Comment: I cannot access other tabs!

Comment: Does this only happen with gtk apps? Also, how have you configured the gtk theme?

Comment: Try to run from terminal, maybe some debug info appear when you try to switch tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved by installing

```
gtk3-engines-oxygen-git
gtk2-engines-oxygen-git
```

from [here](https://launchpad.net/~hrvojes/+archive/kde-goodies).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like its a theme issue, try:

```
sudo apt-get install lxappearance
```

I don't use KDE but I've seen a lot of problems with the KDE themes on 11.10

Comment: It is indeed a theme issue. When using other theme than oxygen - all works fine.